# How process POST with multipart/form-data without Content-Disposition header in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, post, multipartform-data

I am using Sprin Boot and i need to process this type of request:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.0
content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary=482CFA229C8C00EBE48F4FAE633EDB4A0
content-length: 157
x-numbercomps: 1 
user-agent: SAP NetWeaver Application Server (1.0;750)
host: 172.0.0.1:8080
accept-encoding: gzip

--482CFA229C8C00EBE48F4FAE633EDB4A0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 11
X-compId: test.txt

content
--482CFA229C8C00EBE48F4FAE633EDB4A0--
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/**", params = {"create"}, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String createPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                         @RequestParam MultipartFile... files) {
    //do some staff

    return "";
}
```

In the controller there is no error, but the number of MuiltipartFiles is 0

Without Content-Disposition Spring can not recognize MultipartFile.

Anyone have any ideas how to handle it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show your controller and what error message you are getting when you post multipart

Comment: Added controller to main post. There is no error..

Answer (score 0):

I have used your controller and posted multiple files and seems no issue and checked all headers and there was no `Content-Disposition` in my header but I can see all files details.Seems issue is sending request not Spring boot side.

Please see below screenshots:

[image: Multipart file request]

and here is header I received and there is no `Content-Disposition`

[image: Headers]

Comment: Content-Disposition isn't the httpHeader, it's about header of multipartFile part. If you look at raw request, you could see this header. In you case this header contains fileName = "file1".